# How do I set dynamic value in Google chart wrap.setOptions?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using [ChartWrapper](http://code.google.com/intl/no-NO/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#chartwrapperobject) in my Google Chart and I need to use dynamic values in the `wrap.setOptions`.

My current solution is like this:

```
// This works
wrap.setOptions({'width':'300','height':'300','min': '2000'});

//This is NOT working. 'Min' value is ignored
var minimum = get_minimum_value();
wrap.setOptions({'width':'300','height':'300','min': minimum });

wrap.draw(data); <--- This is triggered after I set the options
```

How can I add dynamic values in the wrap.setOptions?

Answer (score 1):

from the doc:

> **draw(opt_container_ref)**
>
> Draws the chart. You must call this method **after any changes** that
>   you make to the chart or data to show the changes.
>
> ```
> opt_container_ref [Optional] - A reference to a valid container
> ```
>
> element on the page. If specified, the chart will be drawn there. If
>   not, the chart will be drawn in the element with ID specified by
>   containerId.

just changing the options won't be enough. You'll need to redraw the graphic

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I am drawing the chart after the options are set. I just didn't add it in the example code above. Added it now though, to illustrate that I am drawing chart after setting options. I have discovered that I can't use `wrap.draw(data,options)` as `options` will be ignored. I can hovever call `draw.getChart` after chart has beemn drawn, set the option and then call `chart.draw`.